# Omit labels from series results PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator, kube-state-metrics

Suppose I write a basic PromQL query like this

Query:
`kube_deployment_spec_replicas{}`

Result:

```
kube_deployment_spec_replicas{deployment="mydeployment",endpoint="myendpoint",instance="myinstance",job="myjob",namespace="default",pod="mypod",service="myservice"}
```

Is there a clean way to omit `instance` and `pod` from the resulted timeseries?

Desired:

```
kube_deployment_spec_replicas{deployment="mydeployment",endpoint="myendpoint",job="myjob",namespace="default",service="myservice"}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can't just drop labels because as the result of your query you need to have unique timeseries' and simply dropping labels would violate that constraint.

Comment: @Oliver These metrics are collected through a kube-state-metrics job. instance and pod labels change for these metrics when the job scales up and down. This causes prometheus alertmanager to potentially change the state of a prometheus alert from firing to pending.

Comment: So are all the metrics the same? Then why not go with Sergio's suggestion to use max or avg to reduce the timeseries to just one per deployment.

Answer (score 25):

Try using something like the following as Sergio already suggested:

```
sum(kube_deployment_spec_replicas) without (instance, pod)
```

This query will remove `instance` and `pod` labels from the result. Note that the query won't work as expected if there are multiple `kube_deployment_spec_replicas` time series with identical `(instance, pod)` set of labels. In this case the query will sum up these time series.

p.s. [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) - PromQL-like query language from Prometheus-like monitoring system - VictoriaMetrics - provides more obvious solution to delete labels with `label_del` function:

```
label_del(kube_deployment_spec_replicas, "instance", "pod")
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of VictoriaMetrics.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Prometheus query operators. You can use avg or sum depending on your use case.

You can check here for more information: [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)

Comment: As shown in the question, my query doesn't use built in functions and using built in functions wouldn't achieve the desired behavior. Also, I'm trying to accomplish this in a clean manner (without nested label_replaces)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sum by (labelName)`, eg:

```sql
sum by (job) (
  rate(http_requests_total[5m])
)
```

This will aggregate all `http_requests_total` metric by its `job` label.

Doc: [https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#:~:text=we%20might%20want%20to%20sum%20over%20the%20rate%20of%20all%20instances](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#:%7E:text=we%20might%20want%20to%20sum%20over%20the%20rate%20of%20all%20instances)